# Usb driver for my phone manufacturer not available in the list

Tags: android, usb-debugging

So I am using Le x526 and I can't seem to find any oem usb driver for it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html)

I even tried getting just the google usb driver . After downloading it I went to *Device Manager*. then to *Other devices*. In *Other Devices* I get *ADB interface* with a yellow mark on it. I tried updating driver software but I get this error [windows was unable to install your adb interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjHri.png)

What do I do now? Does anyone have this manufacturers phone and how do you guys solve this issue?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows

Comment: @quicklearner Thank you so much. That second link worked for me.

Comment: i am glad it helped you, feel free to ask anything, happy coding